# Why can't terminal open my .sh file?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal, webserver, minecraft

I'm trying to run a Minecraft Server with Bukkit in 12.04.

In the `.sh` file I'm using to start the Server, I wrote `java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar` (and then I wrote the location of where the craftbukkit file is).

When I try to run it in terminal, it opens then closes immediately and I can't start the server. How can I keep terminal open and get the file to run?

Comment: Is the file marked as executable? Right click on the file in nautilus (file manager) and goto properties, click on permissions, and see if the box is checked, if not check it then try.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to run a jar-file is

```
java -jar jarfilename.jar
```

Not sure if the order `java filename -jar` causes the problem, but you could try change it.

Did you make the jar executable?

```
sudo chmod a+x file-to-make-executable
```

Navigate to the folder that holds the jar-file and run that command.

Hope this helps